# Xcode does not recognise methods added through categories

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, categories

I've created a category to add methods to `NSManagedObjectModel`. Everything works fine except Xcode keeps throwing warnings about `NSManagedObjectModel` not implementing the methods. How can I force it to recognise the method?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820778/linking-objective-c-categories-in-a-static-library/7664505#7664505

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you `#import` the .h of the category?

Comment: I don't know about the original poster, but I did and it made no difference. At what point does it need to be imported?

Comment: At the begging of every .m file where you're using the function.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I added it to my PCH to save some time, put it in the #ifdef __OBJC__ section.

Comment: Agree with jsapara, note that you might need to restart project to make it take effect.