# Build errors when using ZBarReader controller with SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, linker, barcode

I am working on a barcode reader app in iPhone. I am using the Zbar barcode reader app available on the web. I have tried sample code and it is working perfactly. It is scanning barcodes.
Now I want to fetch the code and pass it as unique Id in my SQLite database.
The problem is when I try to add libraries of both SQLite and barcode. It is giving me errors like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      -[AppDelegate dealloc] in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded] in AppDelegate.o
      -[AppDelegate applicationDocumentsDirectory] in AppDelegate.o
      -[ViewController databaseOpen] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController SaveData:] in ViewController.o
      ...
  "_NSStringFromClass", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
```

I am getting 28 same type of errors..
I have searched on the web. But no one has used bar codes with SQLite. They have used other databases. Can I use an SQLite database to store barcode fetched data? How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Make sure both libraries are added to the framesworks list in the project.

Comment: You need to provide the more detailed linker errors in order to get an idea of what it's complaining about.

Comment: @Rayfleck -See I am using libsqlite3.dylib for SQLite and for barcode reading I am using AVFoundation , QuartzCore,CoreMedia,CoreGraphics,libliconv.2.dylib......So is it possible having clashes among them?

Comment: You'll want to put the error in the main question or on pastie.org or gist.github.com. Not good in comments.

Comment: oh k...I will do.Thanks smparkes

Comment: I have searched a lot for using sqlite database for bardode storage...But I could found in "coredata" database only..Can any one having barcode with sqlite database?

Comment: i think prbolem in your sqlite Implement, if you have no problem then paste your code

Comment: Thanks to all but the problem was with library. I was using reference app which was built for ios4 and in ios5 i had to add one more library for that and it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This links may be useful to you.

Please check them out.

1] [Undefined symbols for architecture i386: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere)

2] Try adding **QuartzCore.framework** to your app if you have not added it

3] Also make sure you have added **all the libraries** that you need to.

Please cross check it as this is generally an error that comes up when some framework or library is missing.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Now it is soled...Thanks for help