# iOS CoreData: Linker Error even after adding it to target's build phases

Tags: ios, core-data, cs193p

I'm following the tutorial CS193p on itunes and running into a problem with the core data lesson.
I've done everything exactly as in the demo (however for a slightly different app than in the lesson) and also included the CoreData Framework under build phases for my project. However it still throws this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CoreDataTableViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_BudgetTableViewController in BudgetTableViewController.o
>   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CoreDataTableViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BudgetTableViewController in BudgetTableViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
>   i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Any idea why? In my BudgetTableViewController.h I've included CoreDataTableViewController.h. And CoreDataTableViewController.h imports 
So I don't know where the problems is?

Comment: Verify that CoreDataTableViewController.m is added to the target ("Target Membership" in the inspector )

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it! But what does this actually mean if that checkmark is checked or unchecked? I don't yet completely understand these target settings anyway...

Comment: If it is unchecked, then the compiled object is not linked to the target executable. That is only useful if you have several targets in the same project.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809477/apple-mach-o-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1/9809815#9809815

Comment: @flexaddicted: That link explains everything nicely, I have voted to close as a duplicate.