# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: while building ioxproject having phonegap framework

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode4.2

I am two days old mac and xcode, I am trying to open iOS project using xcode 4.2.1 and on building I am getting following error. Any help will be appreciated. Application uses phone gap framework.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_BIO_new_mem_buf",
>   referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_EVP_DigestInit", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_EVP_DigestUpdate", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_EVP_MD_CTX_init", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_EVP_PKEY_assign", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_EVP_PKEY_free", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_EVP_PKEY_new", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_EVP_PKEY_size", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_EVP_SignFinal", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_EVP_sha256", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign sign:withDict:] in MessageSign.o   "_SHA256", referenced from:
>         -[MessageSign hash:withDict:] in MessageSign.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere

I just experienced the same thing.