# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RequestHandler"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to send and receive data to the server in Json format.For that i have used the RequestHandler class which handle the request for sending and receiving data.But i m getting this error while running the app.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RequestHandler"...

Comment: Check if RequestHandler.m is actually added to your target.

Comment: You obviously haven't even read the full error message, nor did you try understanding it. It continues like "referenced from -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in AppDelegate.m"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [  Undefined symbols for architecture i386: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from: error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere)

Answer (score 0):

make sure your RequestHandler class is compiled, the class's .m file must be in the list of "compile sources" in "build phases"