# calling code from UAStoreFrontUI.h generating Linker Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, urbanairship.com

I just incorporated UrbanAirship-1.3.3 into my project following the instructions from [the UrbanAirship site](https://urbanairship.com/docs/inapp_client.html) and having `#import`ed the appropriate headers, it compiles fine. However inside my app delegate's method

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:NSDictionary*)launchOptions
```

the line:

```
[UAStoreFront useCustomUI:[UAStoreFrontUI class]];
```

which is now required to use Urban Airship, results in the these linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UAStoreFrontUI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The header file(UAStoreFrontUI.h) imports without issue, but as soon as I call code from it(e.g. [UAStoreFrontUI class]) the linker starts complaining. I find this especially odd as  UAirship.h and UAStoreFront.h are linked and usable without error.

I'm fairly new to xcode, so there may be a build setting or something I'm overlooking but, other than that, at this point I've hit a brick wall and not sure how to procceed. Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: Check that libUrbanAirship.a is being linked in the "Link binary with libraries" section of the target build phase.

Comment: @mattj yup, the file is there under "Link Binary with Libraries". I'm not sure how relevant this might be but, I've gone over the tutorial at least 15 times, and the only deviation I can find is that under "Header Search Paths" in Build Settings the tutorial says to add "../Airship/**". Doing so yields a linker error, so instead I tried "$(SRCROOT)/Airship/**", which works fine but I still get a linker error when accessing code from "UIStoreFrontUI.h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker errors where the result of not adding the .m, .xib and other resource files to `Build Phases` under `Copy Bundle Resources`. It seems the appropriate files must be explicitly added individually, under `Copy Bundle Resources`, as adding the folder in which those files exist does not seem work. This is not documented in the Urban Airship tutorial... for some reason.

The solution I stumbled upon can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere) for further reading

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I have just looked at Urban Airship and `UAStoreFrontUI` is actually just an *example* of a class conforming to the `UAStoreFrontUIProtocol` protocol. i.e. it's not a class that comes in the library.

You should make your own but I guess if you do want to use their example one then you'd need to include `UAStoreFrontUI.h` and `UAStoreFrontUI.m` in your project just like you add your own files to your project.

Comment: I finally managed to figured out the issue after stumbling around the internet for a few hours. thanks for the input, your suggestions definitely helped narrow the search. cheers!