# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDZInfo" (sudzc)

Tags: xcode, sudzc, i386

I'm developing an application with XCode 4.1.1

I added the library from http://sudzc.com/ for consume web services.

When I compile the application, it gives this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDZInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SimpleTableViewAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SoapFault", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The configuration of XCode is Build 2.4 and Deplo yment Target 5.1.

This solution does not working for me because SimpleTableViewAppDelegate.m and RootViewController.m are added  ["You can get this type of error if your class' .m file is not listed under the "Compile Sources" step of the "Build Phases" tab of your target. Normally Xcode does this for you, but sometimes it loses the plot and you need to add the .m file manually"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that the missing files are the ones that contain `SDZInfo` and `SoapFault`.  The two .m files you mention must already be in the project because they are listed as the places where those things are **required**.