# Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios5

while i am trying to build my iOS project where iam using storyboard .
Also using transition and animation classes in my project.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FooterView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WallViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FullScreenView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WallViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HeaderView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WallViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LayoutViewExtention", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WallViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MessageModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WallViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TitleAndTextView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WallViewController.o
  "_RGBACOLOR", referenced from:
      -[WallViewController showViewInFullScreen:withModel:] in WallViewController.o
      -[WallViewController animationEnd:finished:context:] in WallViewController.o
      -[AFKPageFlipper initFlip] in AFKPageFlipper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Have you tried googling the issue? There are tons of results and solutions...

Comment: Have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere)

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to analyse such questions without a project at your eyes. But as they are linker errors and you seem to use one of the latest Xcodes and WallViewController is not standard UIKit class (as far as i know(there is no 'UI' prefix)), i guess that you included the files improperly.
Try to delete references to the WallViewController files and add them again into the project by right clicking the group where you want to put them and then "add files..." (my xcode doesn't like dragging for some unknown reason).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions did the same as you said.Now only left with three errors in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Pls have look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere).
Select project and goto **build phase** and add the missing file "WallViewController.m" to **compile source**.