# Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 error iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

There are no errors in my code itself but when i try to run, I get this error - Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 error iOS. I looked for answers but nothing so far has helped me.  I am sure I am linking to the correct libraries.

Furthermore, The code does work when it's run in a different project by itself.  Essentially, I made the pieces of an app and have run into this problem when getting them to all work together.  Everything is identical between the two apps.  The only real difference is that I am running it along with a coreplot code so i'm not sure if that has anything to do with it?

The error is occurring because of a `TFHipple` element.  Here is a copy of the error :

```
Ld /Users/jyurcho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PennStateStrengthandFitness-epmdweltrbdxujcyuhctckzwibzv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PennStateStrengthandFitness.app/PennStateStrengthandFitness normal i386
cd /Users/jyurcho/Desktop/Testing/PennStateStrengthandFitness
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr    /bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/jyurcho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PennStateStrengthandFitness-epmdweltrbdxujcyuhctckzwibzv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/jyurcho/Desktop/Testing/PennStateStrengthandFitness -F/Users/jyurcho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PennStateStrengthandFitness-epmdweltrbdxujcyuhctckzwibzv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/jyurcho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PennStateStrengthandFitness-epmdweltrbdxujcyuhctckzwibzv/Build/Intermediates/PennStateStrengthandFitness.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PennStateStrengthandFitness.build/Objects-normal/i386/PennStateStrengthandFitness.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -lxml2 -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lCorePlot-CocoaTouch -o /Users/jyurcho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PennStateStrengthandFitness-epmdweltrbdxujcyuhctckzwibzv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PennStateStrengthandFitness.app/PennStateStrengthandFitness
```

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TFHpple", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in psuSecondViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I'm pretty sure I have all the frameworks I need

Comment: What is the full error message- which symbol is not being found?

Comment: Probably you are missing some framework. Agreed with Tolley. Post error.

Comment: I added the error message. I'm sure I have all the frameworks as the program runs fine when it's in a smaller app.

Comment: Possibly covered here?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere

Comment: use _real_ device not the _simulator_, and your issue will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Check your build settings. If everything is correct, try a clean build of the whole project. Xcode is trying to link a simulator build of your app with an iOS device build of Core Plot.

Comment: Thanks but I found the answer...whit worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere