# Getting Error While running BCSharingViewController to share my youtube embeded video?

Tags: iphone

My Error is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BCSharingViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
```

[image: Error picture]

Comment: Did you try googling this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture i386: \_OBJC\_CLASS\_$\_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from: error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere)

Comment: Which API does BCSharingViewController belong to? Is this a ViewController created by you?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this type of error if your class .m file is not listed under the "Compile Sources" step

of the "Build Phases" tab of your target. Insert BCSharingViewController.m class in Build Phases

manually & then check.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere

Comment: if its .m file is present in your code then check in compile sources that BCSharingViewController.m class is present there or not.....if not then add it manually there & then check.

Comment: Have you tried all the solution mention in link that i have provided to you?