# undefined symbol for architecture i386 defacebookComposerViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

i have added all frameworks and set my deployment target 4.3 but i don t know why i am getting this error. can any one help me what i am doing wrong?

```
Ld /Users/malik98b/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/intellegentQuiz-dvsvdwuxvcsnjxhacouhvetzygfd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/intellegentQuiz.app/intellegentQuiz normal i386
    cd /Users/malik98b/Desktop/intellegentQuiz
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/malik98b/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/intellegentQuiz-dvsvdwuxvcsnjxhacouhvetzygfd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/malik98b/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/intellegentQuiz-dvsvdwuxvcsnjxhacouhvetzygfd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/malik98b/Desktop/intellegentQuiz/../../Documents/FacebookSDK -F/Users/malik98b/Desktop/intellegentQuiz/intellegentQuiz -filelist /Users/malik98b/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/intellegentQuiz-dvsvdwuxvcsnjxhacouhvetzygfd/Build/Intermediates/intellegentQuiz.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/intellegentQuiz.build/Objects-normal/i386/intellegentQuiz.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.3 -lz.1.2.5 -framework Security -weak_framework Social -weak_framework Accounts -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Twitter -weak_framework AdSupport -framework MessageUI -lsqlite3.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework FacebookSDK -o /Users/malik98b/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/intellegentQuiz-dvsvdwuxvcsnjxhacouhvetzygfd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/intellegentQuiz.app/intellegentQuiz



Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DEFacebookComposeViewController", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ShareVC.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DETweetComposeViewController", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ShareVC.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKItem", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ShareVC.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKMail", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ShareVC.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: describe more detail..

Comment: How has the framework been created? Is it for device only? Make sure you have selected right scheme at the top while building your app.

Comment: how to select scheme? is it in plist?

Comment: i have made changes in question. check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the .m file is not listed under the "Compile Sources" step of the "Build Phases" tab of your target and you need to add the .m file manually.

credit to Allen pike on this one

[Undefined symbols for architecture i386: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere)

Comment: which .m file i have to add?

Comment: I cant tell you what file isn't being complied, go to summary/Build Phases/Compile resources expand it, press the plus button and look at what blue .m file is in there.  There shouldn't be any.  Add it to the project and it shoudd complie

Comment: i compiled my project but by removing file from compile source :)

Comment: Pleasure glad it helped