# After copying some files over to my project i received these errors, any idea how i would go about fixing this?

Tags: objective-c

```
Ld /Users/alexcov329/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HF_Navigator-azauuargjyhgsufbmentrezohhkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HF\ Navigator.app/HF\ Navigator normal i386
cd "/Users/alexcov329/Documents/HF Navigator"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/alexcov329/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HF_Navigator-azauuargjyhgsufbmentrezohhkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alexcov329/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HF_Navigator-azauuargjyhgsufbmentrezohhkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alexcov329/Desktop/HF\ Navigator -F/Users/alexcov329/Documents/HF\ Navigator -filelist /Users/alexcov329/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HF_Navigator-azauuargjyhgsufbmentrezohhkr/Build/Intermediates/HF\ Navigator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HF\ Navigator.build/Objects-normal/i386/HF\ Navigator.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework CoreData -framework SystemConfiguration -framework RevMobAds -framework AdSupport -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Parse -lz.1.1.3 -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/alexcov329/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HF_Navigator-azauuargjyhgsufbmentrezohhkr/Build/Intermediates/HF\ Navigator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HF\ Navigator.build/Objects-normal/i386/HF\ Navigator_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/alexcov329/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HF_Navigator-azauuargjyhgsufbmentrezohhkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HF\ Navigator.app/HF\ Navigator
```

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this type of error if your class' .m file is not listed under the "Compile Sources" step of the "Build Phases" tab of your target. Normally Xcode does this for you, but sometimes it loses the plot and you need to add the .m file manually.

To do this:

TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class ->Build and Run

SOURCE FOR ANSWER:

[Undefined symbols for architecture i386: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-refere)