# IOS linking with missing architecture i386 (AdSupport.framework)

Tags: ios, linker, ios-simulator, i386, build-settings

I had this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701403/ios-simulator-linker-command-failed) going on, but now I am a little further:

I added this framework to my project:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework
```

Now this works fine if I run the app on any device, however this framework is just for the architectures armv7, armv7s and arm64

When running the app on the simulator, the build fails because the architecture i386 is missing. This is included in:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework
```

How can I achieve that all architectures can be used?  I played a lot with the build-settings but nothing worked so far!

error report:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/app1/app1/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/app1/app1/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: error added to the post

Comment: Most likely `AdSupport.framework` is missing. Can you check?

Comment: @AsifAsif I already told him the same thing in his previous question but he says he has added it correctly.

Comment: if AdSupport would be missing, I could not build and deploy the project to my phone! AdSupport for armv7, armv7s and arm64 is there! but at the same time I need the framework for i386 as well, which is located somewhere else! How can I include both?

Comment: Did you try setting `Build Active Architectures Only` to `NO`.

Comment: its currently set to No

Comment: Then you can only test your app in the architectures that support armv7 or armv6. There is no alternative to it i guess.

Comment: I cannot imagine that. The needed framework is on disk, I just need to add it somehow!

Comment: @Michel I am facing this issue can you kindly inform me how to fix this, I am able to  run project in device but in simulator I am unable to run.

Comment: In the end, I couldnt fix it. Changed the bibs manually depending on where I wanted to run the app. :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Project Target.and make architecture like below image.[image]

Comment: this is not the valid answer, the questioner is missing something else , just ask the full error report

Answer (score 0):

/Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/app1/app1/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport is missing an i386 slice; I suspect that it was likely built for arm and not intel.  It looks like that framework is external to your project, so I suggest you rebuild it for the simulator.

You can check the current architectures of the framework by running `file /Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/app1/app1/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport`