# Linker errors (undefined symbols) with Parse.framework

Tags: ios, parse-platform, linker-errors

I added `Parse.framework` to my project. In AppDelegate.m, I just import it and set the application ID. It seemed OK, but when I run it, I get 4 errors.

What other frameworks should I add, or what else should I do ?

Here are the frameworks I added:

```
AudioToolbox.framework
CFNetwork.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
MobileCoreServices.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib
Parse.framework
```

And here are the errors I am getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Parse(Parse.o)//And other six

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Parse(Parse.o)//And other six

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)//And other six

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Looks like you did not add the Bolts.framework that comes with the Parse SDK

Comment: Did you follow their setup guide?  (From the readout, it appears you did not.)  All of these questions are answered very clearly in their setup guide.  Go back to parse and follow each and every step carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also add the **Bolts.framework** that comes with the Parse SDK as described in Step 2 on the quick start page:

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing.

And ensure it gets listed under "Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries."

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

[Undefined symbols for architecture i386: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-referenc)

Found this.

---

1. This usually happens when you have multiple classes with same name in your. You might have included a file more then once.
2. Also check if you have by any chance imported .m file into some file.