# Errors in demo for video streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

From this link [MediaLibDemos3x](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x)  ,  I downloaded source code and I am running it in X-Code 6.3.2 but I am getting following two errors . Can any one check it please give me a solution?

Error 1-

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BroadcastStreamClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
```

Error 2-

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The link doesn't work. More important, if you say there are errors, you should say which errors, and include relevant code here.

Comment: Now once check it @Antonio

Comment: It sounds like your build settings are messed up. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-referenc

Comment: Did you added required frameworks?

Comment: Yeah just now I checked it but I am not getting . Please once go through that above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the included library are not compiled for i386 (or simulators) so you must run code on real device. See author comment [here](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x/issues/15) and [here](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x/issues/2)

Answer (score 1):

Undefined symbols for architecture i386

You can get this type of error if your class' .m file is not listed under the "Compile Sources" step of the "Build Phases" tab of your target.

To do this:
Target Settings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class ->Build and Run

run your app on device.

Comment: Yeah I have checked it there are .m files but in this project there are three targets are present.

Comment: have you checked in all the targets? check the framework and library requirement also

Comment: Yeah I have checked it.