# copy of a working target has "OBJC_CLASS_" errors

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've a cocos2d project & got two targets "free" & "pro".

The "free" target runs all fine - so i made duplicate of it to turn it into "pro" but this duplicated target gives lots of "_OBJC_CLASS_" errors:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCDirector", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in HelloWorldScene.o
  objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in CleverMouseAppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in LogoSence.o
  objc-class-ref in GameSence.o
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
  ...
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCEaseBounceOut", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCLabelTTF", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in HelloWorldScene.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCLayer", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_HelloWorld in HelloWorldScene.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_LogoSence in LogoSence.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GameSence in GameSence.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_MenuSence in MenuSence.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_EndSence in EndSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCMenu", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GameSence.o
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCMenuItemImage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GameSence.o
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCMoveBy", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCRepeatForever", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCScaleBy", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCScene", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in HelloWorldScene.o
  objc-class-ref in LogoSence.o
  objc-class-ref in GameSence.o
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCSequence", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCSprite", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in LogoSence.o
  objc-class-ref in GameSence.o
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCTexture2D", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in CleverMouseAppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCTextureCache", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GameSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCTransitionFade", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in LogoSence.o
  objc-class-ref in GameSence.o
  objc-class-ref in MenuSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAGLView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in CleverMouseAppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SimpleAudioEngine", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in LogoSence.o
  objc-class-ref in GameSence.o
  objc-class-ref in EndSence.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCLayer", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_HelloWorld in HelloWorldScene.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LogoSence in LogoSence.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GameSence in GameSence.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MenuSence in MenuSence.o
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_EndSence in EndSence.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

note: i've "cocos2d libraries" and it's target membership is switched on for both the targets!

Comment: set i386 in valid architectures.

Comment: all targets have already "standard architectures" set up including arm64 v7 & v7s - so may be i386 doesnt needs to be added separately.  

That didnt work out though.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9438843/285242) and read the comments section as well.

Comment: thanks! :D one of the comment fixed it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to 0xDEADBEEF - found the answer in the post : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-referenc/9438843#9438843/)

i set "build active architecture" to "yes" and all errors gone!

thanks Akshay!