# I am building a simple RSS reader app and got a strange error message

Tags: ios, swift, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I was building an RSS reader based on the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jootsUaCvAU and I got the following error message after attempting to build my app after importing files from the tutorial.

Error Message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWFeedInfo", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.MWFeedInfo in NewsFeedTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWFeedItem", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.MWFeedItem in NewsFeedTableViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWFeedParser", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.MWFeedParser in NewsFeedTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker
```

I do not really know what this means or how to deal with it as I am very new to coding. I highly appreciate any help!

Comment: Search past questions for the same error, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-referenc

Answer (score 0):

Using cocoapods? Try going 'Build Settings' and change 'Enable bitcode' to "no"