# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController", referenced from:

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I am using both Objective-C and Swift languages in a single project.
MainViewController is Objective-C language. I want use this controller method in Swift class using create MainViewController object like:

```
var mainobj = MainViewController()
mainobj.sample
```

I already completed the bridging process and checked compiled source and finally got a clean built project so, what's the problem?
Thanks in advance.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FontList", referenced from: type metadata accessor for __ObjC.FontList in KeyboardViewController.o "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController", referenced from: type metadata accessor for __ObjC.MainViewController in KeyboardViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: can you show the full stack trace

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FontList", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.FontList in KeyboardViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.MainViewController in KeyboardViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: i I'm using both class  FontList & MainViewController

Comment: see this once bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-referenc

Comment: i already try this @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: import your mainViewController in bridge class