# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UBSDKConfiguration", referenced from

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uber-api

My application contains lot's of third part SDK's like Facebook, Google+, Google Analytic, etc. Everything is working great on iOS 7 to latest iOS 10.x beta

Now I want to integrate [UberRides SDK](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk) in my application. Since `UberRides SDK` supports "above iOS 8.x" , I had updated my application & given above iOS 8.x supportability. Now I am getting error

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UBSDKConfiguration", referenced from:
>       objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

I had tried many solutions related to `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:` from here [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

&

[Undefined symbols for architecture i386: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPSMTPMessage", referenced from: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-referenc?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

but nothing worked in my case

Comment: [This solution](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/19#issuecomment-210921399) at uberride official github may help you.

Comment: @pkc456 followed the stuffs but getting same error.

Comment: You need to change the deployment target in the targets tab of your poroject.

Answer (score 0):

Solve my problem by doing following steps -

> Your Application->TARGETS->Build Settings

set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `YES`