# chilkat iOS Integration for encryption and decryption

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

Any one has used this chilkat SDK of `iOS` for encryption and decryption?
how to integrate this in `iOS` app as i am getting error after integrate this to my app.

Error is:
**ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/user/Documents/iOS Project/EncryptionDemo27/EncryptionDemo27/chilkat-9.5.0-ios9/lib/arm64/libchilkatIos.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/user/Documents/iOS Project/EncryptionDemo27/EncryptionDemo27/chilkat-9.5.0-ios9/lib/arm64/libchilkatIos.a**

**Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CkoCrypt2", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-referenc

Comment: have you try this run on device ?? if its working with device that this /libchilkatIos.a file is only for device you need to add simulator also.

Comment: Hello after running app to device i am getting error as beloved:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info", referenced from:

Comment: Don't use chilkat, check [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor), it uses Apple's Common Crypto, is secure, well vetted and currently being maintained.