# iOS: Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, llvm-clang

I'm trying to implement [ios-oauthconsumer](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ios-oauthconsumer) 
but I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAMutableURLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAConsumer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to add the files following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-referenc?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) but Xcode re-adds the file to the project. For example:

[image]
Any of you knows a way were I can add the files to the  "Compile Sources" without having to re-add the file?

I'll really appreciated you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that each source file that needs to be linked is part of the **Compile Sources** section of your target. You can verify this by selecting your project in Navigator pane (as shown in your screenshot) and expanding the section shown here:

[Xcode Compile Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFuxd.png)

You can also verify this by selecting the files and viewing their target membership in the **Utilities** pane in xcode.

[Target Membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dO0s.png)