# SDWebImage : setImageWithURL fails when used to set image of a UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, sdwebimage

When call setImageWithURL, it fails with following,

> *[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x149a20 2011-12-14 18:11:38.060 [781:707]
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView
>   setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x149a20'*

I can confirm I have included `SDWebImage` project and required headers correctly as I can use the SDWebImageManager successfully.

Following is the code where I called the UIImageView category method `setImageWithURL`

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.abc.com/abc.png"];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]];
```

Comment: Can you post the code of where you create the image and call the method so we can have a better idea of what might be going on ?

Comment: Question has updated with requested info. Further, category is defined in UIImageView+WebCache.h file and i have included it in the same file as above code. Looks like this category function is not visible to UIImage view instance. Is there anything else need to be done other than including the header?

Comment: this is quite strange as your code looks fine, the error is really pointing to the category not being found. Are you sure you are importing the category properly? `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"`

Comment: Yes, I had the import correctly. I used the source directly without refer it as a static library. Problem got solved that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up inserting all the .h and .m files into my project and then it worked fine. I got the same error when I only included the .a and .h files.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem the same way.This is not the best way to solve the issue but need to verify force_load attribute mention by Steven.

Comment: @chrizz Even I am facing the same issue.I have included all the SDWebImage files to my project, no header settings done.I know i m missing something here. Kindly point me where i m wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I Solved the same problem adding the libSDWebImage.a to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries

Comment: Where do you add libSDWebImage from?

Comment: You need to add all the .m files. that would fix the problem

Comment: I did. But I still have this problem

Comment: @Odelya Were you bale to solve it? Added all the .h and .m files, but couldn't solve the problem. Neither did I find where the .a file is. Is the .a file generated when the SDWebImage source code is compiled? Neither Did I get it that way.

Comment: I had a different problem - the tag of the item that I wanted to check wasn't an UIImageView

Answer (score 18):

As per:
[linking objective-c categories in a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820778/linking-objective-c-categories-in-a-static-library)

Due to a linker bug in XCode, you need to set the 'Other Linker Flags' setting your build target.  Setting the flag as follows should eliminate this error.

```
-force_load ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libSDWebImage.a
```

Comment: I'm confused about how to add the files to the project. I copied the SDWebImage folder into my project's directory (via terminal). This includes the SDWebImage.xcodeproj file. Then I right click the project in Xcode and click 'Add Files...' which copies in the folder and all the contents, PLUS the .xcodeproj file which expands to the same files AGAIN in a folder structure, and the libSDWebImage.a file (red). I want to keep the file size down, so is this necessary? (I added the folder to my proj's header search paths) but get the above error even with Other Linker Flags set. *confused

Comment: That's a little excessive.  Just drag the SDWebImage.xcodeproj to your project.  Set "Target Dependencies" and "Link Binary With Libraries" in the build phases of your project target.  Finally, add the above flag to force the category to load.

Comment: If you are using ARC Compliant SDWebImage, you'll have to add the following line: -force_load ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libSDWebImageARC.a

Comment: has anybody tried this thing on xcode 4.5? I am not able to resolve the problem..

Comment: @user739711 yes i just resolved it for xcode 4.5, i added the arc framework in "target dependencies" but i had forgotten to add libSDWebImage.a (w/ arc support) to "link binary with libraries"

Comment: Im confused, are you saying drag the xcodeproj fileinto my project??

Comment: This is for adding ZXing but the principle is the same. http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/

Comment: Where do I download the static lib from?

Comment: It may have changed, but try here: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/wiki/Download-Complied-Framework

Answer (score 11):

This will solve the problem: Open the "Build Settings" tab, in the "Linking" section, locate the "Other Linker Flags" setting and add the "-ObjC" flag:
[image]

Comment: this does not help me, i was like this

Comment: Add ImageIO.framework and QuartzCore.framework before add '-ObjC' flag into 'Other Linker Flags' section.

Comment: Thank you Arash! None of the answers to the question worked but your comment worked.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone, like me, still has problems after seeing all the other answers here (e.g. force_load or load_all) even after following all the proper installation instructions, here is what I have learnt after doing some search online:

- This problem only happens when you use iPhone 5S or the 64-bit simulator
- This is a problem with libwebp

**The solution to this problem:**
*Only do this if you don't need the 64-bit processor for your app (too new to iOS programming to know if this sentence is valid)*

1. Go to build settings > Architecture
2. Under Architecture, select `Standard architectures (armv7,armv7s)`
3. Under Build Active Architecture Only, make sure it is **Yes** for both `Debug` and `Release`

My source: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/494

I hope this helps those who, like me, found this while trying to solve your problem =)

Comment: Tried everything in this thread. The only thing that have worked for me.
Seems to run fine on the 64bit emnulator nontheless.

Answer (score 4):

In the SDWebImage docs, it says that you have to set "Other Linker Flags" to -ObjC.  This did not work for me.  Instead, I set it to -all_load.  I also had to remove -ObjC.  The explanation for what is going on can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html

It also explains why -ObjC fails: *"Important: For 64-bit and iPhone OS applications, there is a linker bug that prevents -ObjC from loading objects files from static libraries that contain only categories and no classes. The workaround is to use the* f-all_load *or* -force_load *flags"*

Using -all_load increases the size of the executable.  You can use -force_load to mitigate this somewhat.  For SDWebImage 2.7.3, I did this by setting the following in "Other Linker Flags" in the Build Settings: "-load_all $(SRCROOT)/SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage".  Linking to libSDWebImage[ARC].a which is what some sources advise, didn't work for me.

Incidentally, in Xcode 4.4, it seems you have to do a slow double-click in order to change build settings properly.  Doing a normal double-click shows the completely screwed up and non-working pop-up.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the same problem adding the libSDWebImage.a to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the document here https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage at the bottom there is a **download** link with the CORRECT files to [download](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/wiki/Download-Complied-Framework). Following that example it works perfectly.

The mistake I made, and seemingly others to, is I downloaded the github project and tried using that.

Comment: But I want to add the source files and not only reference

Answer (score 1):

Everything started to work for me once I linked "ImageIO.framework" to my main project.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set 'Other Linker Flags' to -all_load.  This solves the problem where an external framework (such as the filepicker framework) requires linking against SDWebImage.

Answer (score 0):

-force_load is not fix fundamental problem (when achiveing problem happens)
to fix this linking problem..

1. edit scheme for SDWebImage,
2. run scheme set for release
3. run (with device)
4. libSDWebImage.a  will be generated in release-iphoneos directory.
5. set target->BuildPhase->link Binarywithlibrary .. add this lib.
6. Done..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your compiled files have UIIMageView+AFNetworking.m in case you're using AFNetworking framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the libSDWebImage.a in your linked binaries, also check for other linker flags, it should be -ObjC

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your choice when you pull files of SDWebimages into Xcode, do mark the "create groups" in added folders, and do not mark the "create folder references".

Mark exactly as the picture:

[image]