# Getting unrecognized selector after removing other frameworks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Edit: I found the solution here [SDWebImage : setImageWithURL fails when used to set image of a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504953/sdwebimage-setimagewithurl-fails-when-used-to-set-image-of-a-uitableviewcell?rq=1)

I have UITableView that's utilizing SDWebImage and it worked great but I decided to remove ShareKit from my app. All I believe I did was delete ShareKit, remove any references to it and then reinstall ObjectiveFlickr, JSONKit and LFWebAPIkit. All of which I don't use in this table. After I did that, everything works, except for this tableview.

I get this error:

```
-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x86b31a0
```

I have no problem compiling and with autocomplete and I even deleted and readdded SDWebImage but it doesn't do anything. Everything runs fine but when it tries to load the table with the UIImageView it crashes immediately on this line:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[v thumbURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"46-movie-2.png"]];
```

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YTVVideoTableCell";

YTVVideoTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[YTVVideoTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Video *v = [[[VideoStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];;

[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[v thumbURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"46-movie-2.png"]];

[cell setController:self];
[cell setTableView:[self tableView]];

[[cell titleLabel] setText:[v title]];
[[cell titleLabel] alignBottom];

return cell;
```

}

Any ideas of what went wrong when I removed ShareKit? Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDWebImage : setImageWithURL fails when used to set image of a UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504953/sdwebimage-setimagewithurl-fails-when-used-to-set-image-of-a-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [SDWebImage : setImageWithURL fails when used to set image of a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504953/sdwebimage-setimagewithurl-fails-when-used-to-set-image-of-a-uitableviewcell?rq=1)

I added "-force_load ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libSDWebImageARC.a" to my build settings "Other Linker Flags" and it now works.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve the problem: Open the "Build Settings" tab, in the "Linking" section, locate the "Other Linker Flags" setting and add the "-ObjC" flag:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have imported the SDWebImage header into your class.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using `SDWebImage` through Cocoapods. Turns out, the `SDWebImage` pod was listed under the incorrect target in the Podfile. Moving it to the top of the file worked for me.