# iOS SDWebImage unrecognized selector complete-block

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, unrecognized-selector, sdwebimage

I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) in my iPhone project to load and cache images automatically. The basic usage works perfect:

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:*url*]];
```

But when I use ANY of the other methods with extra parameter options, like the one I would like to use, with a completion block:

```
[self.posterImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Utils getMoviePosterUrlForMovie:movie withSize:PosterSizeBig]]
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) { }];
```

I get the error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:completed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

All the other problems and solutions I found with the unrecognized selector error, were problems with the whole library where the basic "setImageWithURL"-method also didn't work.

What could be the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: did you include UIImageView+WebCache.m in the files to compile for your target?

Answer (score 1):

That was problem i face too, I solve by set flag in Build Settings>TARGETS>Linking>Other Linker Flags

-force_load ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libSDWebImage.a

as shown in this link:

[SDWebImage : setImageWithURL fails when used to set image of a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504953/sdwebimage-setimagewithurl-fails-when-used-to-set-image-of-a-uitableviewcell)

a little late, but hope this help