# Images wont get cached when using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, uitableview, caching, sdwebimage, unrecognized-selector

I cant get SDWebImage to work correctly.

I have  UITableView with images that are always showing, yet the cache is always empty.

in other words, the images are not connected to the SDWebImage cache.

Also, Im getting the error **unrecognized selector sent to instance** when calling for:

**setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:**

however the error is gone when Im using

**setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:**

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this how I do and it cache image properly

```
[cell.img setImageWithURL:imgURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"somePlaceholder.png"]];
```

mind telling why you want to use `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:` ?

Comment: this is working for me, without the cache. I dont really need to use setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options: ,but that indicated for a problem

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today and I was actually picking up AFNetworking's `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` instead of SDWebImage. I bet this happens more than people realize.

Make sure you `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` if you use their static library/framework, or simply `#import UIImageView+WebCache` if you imported the .h and .m files of SDWebImage. You might have to delete AFNetworking's `UIImageView+AFNetworking` files completely, depending on what version you have.

If you've done that, double check your `Other linker flags` in Build Settings has the `-ObjC` specification. And if that gives you hell, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504953/sdwebimage-setimagewithurl-fails-when-used-to-set-image-of-a-uitableviewcell).