# I have custom ios framework and i want to add some method to frameworks gives me an error "unrecognized selector sent to instance "

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-frameworks

I try to delete Derived data so it can reload the new files, but still the same error, can anybody have idea how to add methods to framework? Or i have to decompile the framework and add some methods and compile it again?
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442653/unrecognized-selector-calling-category-method-in-static-ios-library

Comment: Give the the whole error message, it's often giving you hint: Class Object, Method signature, and callback trace.

Comment: Tushar I have tried this also but didnt work. Larme it is not the problem with the method, but Framework is using old code, so it thinks there is no method like that. so it generates 'NSInvalidArgumentException' unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: When you say "add methods to framework", how are you trying to do that?  A category?

Comment: if i add in header file - (void)myMethod; and in implementation file - (void)myMethod {
    NSLog(@"myMethod Called");
}
 when i am trying to call [a myMethod]; it gives me an error