# iOS Static Library and NSInvalidArguementException error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I successfully created a iOS static library containing the LRResty API along with many of my own classes, functions etc.  To try testing my library, I copied it over to a new Xcode project along with the libraries header file.  In this new Xcode project I invoked one of my functions that eventually calls the LRResty function [LRRestyClient get:withBlock:].  This then throws the exception NSInvalidArguementException unrecognized selector sent to instance.  The interesting thing is that I can right-click on the function (within the static library) and "Jump to definition" and it knows where the function definition lies.

I know this exception can be thrown for many reasons, does anyone know what else it might be?  I'd be happy to provide more information if this description is too vague.  Or could anyone please explain to me how to package the LRResty library successfully into a iOS static library?  I will then use this process to package the rest of my source files within it.

Note: I'm new to creating static libraries, so it could be something very simple that I overlooked.  I followed this tutorial to create my static library: http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What do you see when you tell the debugger to break on exceptions being thrown?

Comment: The debugger stops on the line [[LRResty client] get:requestURL withBlock:^(LRRestyResponse *response) when I enable break on exceptions. I'm not too familiar with assembly, is there something I should look for in the assembly within the stack trace?

Comment: I don't think looking at the assembly will help. But if I were you, I'd look at the block and the requestURL and see if I could determine if there's anything wrong with them. You're getting an NSInvalidArgumentException. Does the console display any information about the exception? Usually that exception comes from the OS getting a bad value. Maybe if it tells you the address of the bad data you could examine it and determine what might be wrong?

Comment: The interesting thing is if I put the [[LRResty client] get:requestURL withBlock:^(LRRestyResponse *response) directly in the test app's ViewDidLoad() function and include the LRResty headers, I get the same error.  I know the basics about static libraries (not an expert by any means)...could it be that my library does not contain LRResty's source code (.m files) somehow?

Comment: OK, found the source of my problem.  LRResty uses categories and iOS static libraries do not play nice with categories.  Looks like I need to include a few linker flags to solve the problem.  I'll report a solution once I figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a result of the LRResty library using categories.  To fix this problem, I had to add the compiler flags -ObjC and -all_load to the build targets *Other Linker Flags* section. Note: these compiler flags were added to my Sample App which is making use of the library I created.  Thus, any app that uses my library would have to insert these compiler flags.

Here is some more information regarding using categories within an iOS static library:

> Objective-C does not define linker symbols for each function (or method, in Objective-C) - >instead, linker symbols are only generated for each class. If you extend a pre-existing class with >categories, the linker does not know to associate the object code of the core class implementation >and the category implementation. This prevents objects created in the resulting application from >responding to a selector that is defined in the category.
>
> **To resolve this issue, the target linking against the static library must pass the -ObjC option >to the linker**. This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an >Objective-C class or category. While this option will typically result in a larger executable (due >to additional object code loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of >effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on existing classes.
>
> **Important**: For 64-bit and iPhone OS applications, there is a linker bug that prevents -ObjC from >loading objects files from static libraries that contain only categories and no classes. The >workaround is to use the -all_load or -force_load flags.

Information above retrieved from this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820778/linking-objective-c-categories-in-a-static-library) answer.