# CocoaPods pods crashes

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a project with CocoaPods and it was great, until I started having some problems.

I am using a pod for `UIActionSheet` and `UIAlertView` with blocks which extends those classes with category.

I added the pods to the .podsfile and imported the headers to my project. When I add the code to the project Xcode does not complain about nothing and I even see the category methods in the autocompletion suggestions.

But, when I run the app, it always crashes on the category method execution  saying that "unrecognized selector sent to (`UIActionSheet` or `UIAlertView`)".

I have added the classes directly to my project and it works great so I think this is CocoaPods problem.

Here as an example of code:

```
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        RIButtonItem *selectPhotoButton = [RIButtonItem itemWithLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"Choose from library",nil) action:^{
            [self selectPhoto];
        }];
        RIButtonItem *takePhotoButton = [RIButtonItem itemWithLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"Take a photo",nil) action:^{
            [self takePhoto];
        }];
        UIActionSheet *ac = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Image source",nil) cancelButtonItem:[RIButtonItem itemWithLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil)] destructiveButtonItem:nil otherButtonItems:takePhotoButton,selectPhotoButton, nil];
        [ac showInView:self.view];
    }
    else
    {
        [self selectPhoto];
    }
```

The app crashes on `initWithTitle:cancelButtonItem:destructiveButtonItem:otherButtonItems`

And this is my Podsfile

```
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'UIAlertView-Blocks'
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: Can you post your `Podfile` and some example code that is crashing your app?

Comment: OK that looks fine to me. Did you run `pod install` after editing your podfile and are you using the `.xcworkspace` file?

Comment: Also ensure you import using `#import <UIAlertView-Blocks/UIActionSheet+Blocks.h>`

Comment: As I said - Xcode recognises the methods and eve suggests auto completion. Thanks

Comment: Well I created a new project and used your code along with that import statement and it works fine. So there has to be something else. I also used this pod in a project at work yesterday and it works fine. Why not show your import statement? Also you might want to confirm which build of Xcode and iOS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer here -
[linking objective-c categories in a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820778/linking-objective-c-categories-in-a-static-library)

I was missing the -ObjC flag in other linker flags which was required for static libraries that implements categories.

Thanks anyway